# Can I chain-call a shell command from Laravel Mix?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, laravel-mix-vue3

I use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) - it's a flexible way to use webpack easily.

When running `watch` it will recompile dev mode builds whenever the files change. However, in order to use these there's an external build step - e.g. one project needs to call `drush cc css-js` .

Is there a way to do this from the `webpack.mix.js` file or other?

Sort of like:

```
mix()
 .js('src/app.js', 'dist/')
 .vue()
 .shell('drush cc css-js') // ««« something like this?
;
```

OR perhaps it has to go in the `package.json`'s `.scripts` bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use **Event Hooks** to this end.

In **Laravel Mix v6**, you can use [Event Hooks (v6)](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/event-hooks) like this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist/')
   .vue()
   .after(() => {
        exec('drush cc css-js');
    });
```

If you want to execute something before compiling the resources, use `mix.before()` instead of `mix.after()`.

**Edit**: As OP has pointed out below, in **Laravel Mix v5**, you had to use an [Event Hook (v5)](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/event-hooks) `mix.then()` to run arbitrary code after executing the mix. There was no Event Hook to run code before executing the mix.

Comment: Excellent! thanks so much (and welcome to StackOverflow!) I found [docs for child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and note that in Mix v5 you have to use `then()` in place of `after()`.